# Punctured and taped lithium-ion battery for phone

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, cellphone

My phone was bulging more and more in a span of weeks. I decided to open it and remove the battery, as most likely cause. While removing it from the heavy duty adhesive, I punctured it and a little black smoke came out. I immediately opened windows and turned on the HEPA air purifier. The battery bulge went away though, so I taped it to close the puncture and put it back in the phone. No fires, charges just fine, more than a month after. Many in this forum believe it should be thrown away.

Do you think it is still an hazard? What about flying with this phone, since air in planes may have more oxygen?

Thanks

Comment: For maximum safety, yes, throw it away. The worst thing about (damaged) lithium batteries is that they can burst into fire at the most unexpected moment, e.g. while in your pants, or while you're sleeping.

Comment: I agree with @akwky, but the battery should be handed in for correct disposal/recycling.

Comment: This is Darwinism in action.

Comment: Search for phone battery explosion on youtube.

Comment: _"What about flying with this phone, since air in planes may have more oxygen?"_ No such thing. Lower pressure yes but the oxygen concentration remains the same.

Comment: this site is not a forum

Comment: Why are you even asking, think about it. If someone here would say: It's absolutely fine what you're doing! So you carry on and next week the battery catches fire and the aircraft you were on had to make an emergency landing. Who will pay the bill? You or the guy advising you to carry on? What would the airline company say if you said: "But the guy on SEEE said this would be safe." They would laught in your face and you'd still have to pay the bill anyway. So for your own safety and those of others: get a new battery.

Answer (score 2):

A puffed up battery is a hazard and a punctured battery is a hazard. The battery was already damaged and you damaged it more by puncturing it. It can still explode or start a fire, damaging your phone and contents in it, or it might stop working at any moment, also preventing the use of phone until the battery is replaced.